# Graph toolkit Mgt-react Get photo value

Tags: microsoft-graph-toolkit

> <Get resource="/me/photo/$value" scopes={['user.read']} maxPages={2} type='image'>
> // Type '"image"' is not assignable to type 'ResponseType | undefined'.
> <MyPhoto template="value>
>
> When i try to specify the type in the Get this what i get, with out that templateprops are empty
>
> const MyMessage = (Props: MgtTemplateProps)=>{
> const photo=Props.dataContext;   /// this is empty
> return(<></>)
> }

error: Type '"image"' is not assignable to type 'ResponseType | undefined'
how to retrieve the image url by using URL.createObjectURL

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the type ResponseType to identify you want an image and use the `default` template instead of the value as it's not an array.. This is how I've been doing it :

```
<Get resource="/me/photo/$value" type={ResponseType.image}>
    <MyPhoto template='default' />
</Get>
```

And the `MyPhoto` component should be the following :

```
const MyPhoto = (props: MgtTemplateProps) => {
  const { image } = props.dataContext;
  return <img src={image} />;
};
```